# url of each listed nodes in a view using the content format

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

How can I display a node link for each node listed in a view with a content format parameter?

I have set a view with a content format teaser and the template is 
 node--article--teaser.html.twig.

`<a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">` displays the page link where the view is displayed, not the content.link.

I cannot figure out why it does not work in my site and what could interfere with it.

The only way around I found was to get the node ID with   `content.links['#lazy_builder'][1][0]`.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments of the default node.html.twig under /core/modules/node/templates/. Any variable listed there should also work in node--article--teaser.html.twig.